# tinymce build script to compress all js files

Tags: javascript, ant, compression, tinymce, yui-compressor

I am looking for a way to compress all tinymce js files into one single file.

I would like to use ant, yui-compressor and a build script. There seems to exist something like this already:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce

But i have not been able to make it work.
**Can anybody with experience give me some assistance?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from the tinymce forum (Spocke):

1. Install Java.
2. Install ant
3. Add ant to environment variable "path"
4. Open a console
5. cd to the tinymce dir and type "ant build_full"

Answer (score 2):

We're using tinymce in our commercial grade productions. At first, we used their default .NET compressor. But, we've found it's too buggy for a real production. Then we made a simple IHttpHandler to concatenate given JavaScript files and JavaScript snippets. The handler also take advantages of caching to reduce response time. There should be some third party solutions if you don't want to waste your time.

Comment: what is buggy, can you give examples?

Comment: Sorry. I can't clearly remember (it's around 2 years ago). But, I'm sure there were some serious bugs.