# Tinymce compress other than tinyMCE_GZ.init

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In continuation with the below post is there any way to take ahead the build.xml and add all the plugins such as table, save etc and compress it with the same build.xml file. Reason is to have one ant script file to compress all the files into one, not only the tinymce js files but also other project related files.

[tinymce build script to compress all js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787744/tinymce-build-script-to-compress-all-js-files/11351965#11351965)

I know the compressio is possible by declaring additional tinyMCE_GZ.init but why use two methods of the compression in same project. It would nice to have as described in above post using build.xml.

How does the plugin structure works it is possible to take everything in one file & still intantiate plugin, right now when I take out all the script tag from table plugin (i.e from table.htm) file I get javascript error even though the script tag is available into the parent html file from which table plugin is invoked..

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, but i failed. I won't say it is impossible, but it will be pretty difficult to achieve. What i ended up doing is to use two compessing methods.